# Delete SAP HANA Views

Tags: hana

Is there a way to schedule deletion of sap hana views after a period of time ? We have one requirement where developers create temporary views and forgot to delete those. In such cases we are facing issues with views migration because if any of the temp view is referring that model then out TR gets failed because of the changes in original model.

I am looking for a utility or a way to bulk delete the temp views after certain time duration of creation.